# "Excel VBA - Error: "We found a problem with some content in..." using Change Event"

Tags: excel, vba

"I am encountering an issue when working with a VBA code in an Excel file that uses the change event. The error message I am seeing is "(we found a problem with some content in...)". I have tried troubleshooting the problem but have not been able to resolve it. Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this error and how to fix it?

This is the VBA CODE

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wsInput As Worksheet
Dim rngInput As Range
Dim rngOutput As Range
Dim strOptions As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim rngB As Range, rngF As Range, rngA As Range
'Input sheet
Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
Set rngInput = wsInput.Range("A2:C" & wsInput.Cells(wsInput.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

'Check for changes in column A or B
If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 2 Then
    'Output sheet - set range to same row as change
    Set rngOutput = Target.Worksheet.Range("C" & Target.Row & ":C" & Target.Row)
    rngOutput.Validation.Delete
    strOptions = ""
    For i = 2 To rngInput.Rows.Count
        If rngInput.Cells(i, 1) = Target.Worksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 1) And rngInput.Cells(i, 2) = Target.Worksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 2) Then
            strOptions = strOptions & rngInput.Cells(i, 3) & ","
        End If
    Next i
    If strOptions <> "" Then
        strOptions = Left(strOptions, Len(strOptions) - 1) 'remove last comma
        rngOutput.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=strOptions
    End If
End If

'Target range for column B and F
Set rngB = Target.Worksheet.Range("B2:B" & Target.Worksheet.Rows.Count)
Set rngF = Target.Worksheet.Range("F2:F" & Target.Worksheet.Rows.Count)
Set rngA = Target.Worksheet.Range("A2:A" & Target.Worksheet.Rows.Count)

On Error GoTo Cleanup


'Check for changes in column B => A
If Not Intersect(Target, rngA) Is Nothing Then
For Each cell In Intersect(Target, rngA)
With Target.Worksheet.Range("B" & cell.Row)
.Validation.Delete
Select Case cell.Value
    Case "CUTTING-2-":
        .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="IS,IH,DH"
    Case "ASSEMBLY-2-":
        .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="IS,IH,DH"
    Case Else
        .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="IS,IH"
End Select
End With
Next cell

End If

'Check for changes in column B
If Not Intersect(Target, rngB) Is Nothing Then
For Each cell In Intersect(Target, rngB)
With Target.Worksheet.Range("I" & cell.Row)
.Validation.Delete
Select Case cell.Value
Case "IH": .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="YES,NO"
Case "IS": .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="NA"
Case "DH": .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="NA"
End Select
End With
Next cell

'Check for changes in column F
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, rngF) Is Nothing Then
For Each cell In Intersect(Target, rngF)
With Target.Worksheet.Range("J" & cell.Row)
.Validation.Delete
Select Case cell.Value
Case "Replacement": .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="Definitive, temporary"
Case "Investment": .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="NA"
End Select
End With
Next cell
End If
'Check for changes in column F => K

For Each cell In Intersect(Target, rngF)
With Target.Worksheet.Range("K" & cell.Row)
.Validation.Delete
Select Case cell.Value
Case "Replacement": .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=ISNUMBER(K" & cell.Row & ")"
Case "Investment": .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="NA"
End Select
End With
Next cell


'Check for changes in column F => L

For Each cell In Intersect(Target, rngF)
With Target.Worksheet.Range("L" & cell.Row)
.Validation.Delete
Select Case cell.Value
Case "Replacement": .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=ISTEXT(L" & cell.Row & ")"
Case "Investment": .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="NA"
End Select
End With
Next cell


Cleanup:
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: @JohnColeman this is what I ask for , I don't know the Line

Comment: When you encounter an error and select the "debug" option -- doesn't it highlight the offending line? If your error handling is hiding the error from you, you could comment that out while you are debugging.

Comment: The code is working fine and there are no debugging issues. However, when I close the file and open it again, it becomes corrupted and I lose my work.

Comment: If the code is corrupting the file that contains it, in what sense is it working fine? What happens if you comment out `On Error GoTo Cleanup`? That might be hiding a bug.

Comment: It is possible that the corruption in the file has nothing to do with the macro but just shows up when you try to make any changes to it. You might need to fix the file rather than fix the code.

Comment: @JohnColeman you right there was some hiding bugs.